# Scaffolding with Grails - How to use custom actions for custom views with the templates plugin

Tags: model-view-controller, grails, scaffolding

I need to build my own view which can be displayed by the default scaffolding mechanism. I've already installed the templates plugin with which you can modify the default layout of domain classes, controllers, views and a lot more.

Therefore i've designed my own layout with the thought to display just forms and lists of data. Especially when i need to add some data via AJAX i need to load the rendered form for that via a scaffolded controller in a div-container.

My controller looks like this:

```
class DummyController {
 static scaffold = true

 def ajx_create() {
    render(view: "ajx_create")
 }
}
```

Calling the function render('hello world') within the action ajx_create works but trying to call render(view:'ajx_create.gsp') does not.

How can i configure the scaffolding mechanism to display this new file called ajx_create.gsp?
Is this even possible?

I'm grateful for any help!

Comment: Is ajx_create a new view or is in the scaffolded views? If not, then put ajx_create.gsp in views/dummy

Comment: the view ajx_create is part of the scaffolded views. (src/.../templates/..). when i put the new view in views/dummy i can't call it dynamically...am i wrong?

Comment: You must call "grails generate-views 'your domain class'" command before render the view

Comment: My plan was to call a scaffolded view called ajx_create without generating so many views and customizing it... currently i do have 43 domain classes and its getting more. my need was to call these views without generating them manually. just like when i call localhost:8080/myproject/dummy/show/2. i do not have any views manually generated for this. its generating the view automatically during the runtime. 
why isn't it possible to call localhost:8080/myproject/dummy/ajx_show/2? that's all what i want to know.

Comment: I think it isn't possible to do that. But you can generate only the view you want to render manually as a workaround (and delete the others).

Comment: i know, but it would be great if i could do this automatically...it's a pity.

thx a lot!